# How to read string from a C structure when no field is available?

Tags: c#, interop

There's a C structure which is written to the socket on the other side. I am reading in C#. The structure is like follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct StupidStruct
{
    // fid sequence
    public short fid_seq;

    // field value length, after the length, follow the field content
    public ushort length;
}
```

After reading this from socket, I need to read the string that I receive. The layer I do this does not have access to the buffer itself. It only has access to the structure. How to do this?

EDIT :

The function where I need to do this:

```
public void Handle(ref StupidStruct s)
{
    //GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(s.length, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    //var ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    //ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, sizeof (ushort));

    //The above is my initial attempt. But I think the address I get here is not the buffer address. What to do?

    handle.Free();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So are you reading it in c or C#? Which one is listening on the socket? If C# is, skip the interop and read the bytes off the wire directly. Otherwise you need to do some research, because you will need an intptr to the start of the char array to do anything. Structs are value types, so getting the address if the struct is pointless as it is on the stack anyway.